# Map array of values to generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, reflection, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a function to map array of string values to a generic type in Typescript. The index of the value in the array has the same index as the key in the object. For instance:

I have a `Person` interface

```js
interface Person {
    lastName: string;
    firstName: string;
}
```

An array of values

```js
const values = ['foo', 'bar']
```

And the desired result is an instance of `Person`

```js
{
    lastName: 'foo',
    firstName: 'bar'
}
```

The desired function type should look like something like this

```js
const parse = <T extends Record<string, string | undefined>>(values: Array<string | undefined>)<T> => {
  ...
}

const result: Person = parse(['foo', 'bar']);
```

Mapping 2 arrays to one object is no problem but i want the typing of the returned generic to make things easier. Things like `Object.keys(T)` or `for key in T` does not work so it's hard to get an index of a key.

You can pass a generic with 100 properties and an array with 5 values and only the first 5 properties should be assigned, the others are null or undefined. Vice versa as well, you can pass a generic with 3 properties and an array with 100 values, but only the first 3 are used. The array can contain `undefined or null`

Comment: should `parse` always expect two elements array?

Comment: No you can pass a generic with 100 properties and an array of 5 long and only the first 5 should be assigned, the others are null of undefined. Vice versa as well, you can pass a generic with 3 properties and an array of 100 values long, but only the first 3 are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that all information about types gets erased when your code is compiled. This means that during runtime, your function will have no idea about `Person` and its properties.

To write such a function, you need to provide it with some information about the object that will be returned. One possible way to do that is by defining a class instead of an interface, and adding a parameter to your function that accepts a constructor.

```js
class Person {
    lastName = ""
    firstName = ""
}

type Constructor<T> = { new(): T }

function parse<T>(constructor: Constructor<T>, values: unknown[]): T {
    const obj = new constructor()
    // now you can call Object.keys(obj) and the like
    // ...
}

const result = parse(Person, ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: Hey Loris, thanks for the answer! But when i check `obj` from `new constructor()` the properties are not initialized and so `Object.keys(obj)` returns an empty array

Comment: i played a bit with your piece of code and i found the missing piece. You need to give a default value to the members in the class like `lastname!: string = ''`. Then it works!

Comment: Indeed, uninitialized class properties may get skipped when compiled, so giving them a default values is probably better. In that case however, you should remove the exclamation marks. I edited my answer.